# How do I copy certain cells from one sheet to another conditional on the cell value in both sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, copy, multiple-conditions

I have a range of non-contiguous cells that I want to copy across from one sheet (wseDNA1) to a second sheet (wsElog1). I only want to copy if the value in wseDNA1 is not "NR", and if the cell in wsElog1 does not already contain a value.
I wanted to do a loop, but am not sure how to do this without it looking at every cell, and not just the cells I want to copy. Below is an example of the copy range without the conditional rules. I will have more than a hundred of these to map across every day.

````
wsElog1.Range("BP" & RowNum) = wseDNA1.Range("AE12") 
wsElog1.Range("BQ" & RowNum) = wseDNA1.Range("AG12") 
wsElog1.Range("BN" & RowNum) = wseDNA1.Range("AO12") 
wsElog1.Range("BR" & RowNum) = wseDNA1.Range("AQ12") 
wsElog1.Range("BS" & RowNum) = wseDNA1.Range("AS12") ```
````

Comment: Additionally, each cell from the first sheet goes to a cell in the second sheet that isn't necessarily in the same order as the first sheet.

Comment: If you have a hundred of those column combinations, you will want to write them into consecutive columns on another ((very) hidden) worksheet, instead of hard-coding them into the code. That is what the worksheets are for. If you loop through the elements of an array instead of the cells of the worksheet, the code will be as fast as possible. Please share the complete code, screenshots of your worksheets, and the name of the worksheet that you will use for the column combinations  (exclude the `12` from the list) to possibly get a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Loop and Conditionally Copy Values

- This is how far I got. If you can share the information that I asked for in your comments, it will get better.

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    ' Make sure these two have the same number of elements
    ' and that they are correctly associated.
    Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array("AE", "AG", "AO", "AQ", "AS")
    Dim eCols() As Variant: eCols = VBA.Array("BP", "BQ", "BN", "BR", "BS")
    
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(dCols)
    
    Dim dVal As Variant, RowNum As Long, n As Long, eCol As String
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(dCols)
        dVal = wsDNA1.Cells(12, dCols(n)).Value
        If StrComp(CStr(dVal), "NR", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            eCol = eCols(n)
            For RowNum = 2 To 3 ' adjust!
                If Len(CStr(wsElog1.Cells(RowNum, eCol).Value)) = 0 Then
                    wsElog1.Cells(RowNum, eCol).Value = dVal
                End If
            Next RowNum
        End If
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I will go through this later for more understanding. I don't have the ability to have a hidden sheet because of how these sheets are used. However looking at your code here it has occurred to me (though I will have to think further to be certain) that I may just be able to filter out the "NR" values AFTER doing the copy. I'm pretty sure now that they won't overwrite any useful data that I need (which is what I thought they would do).

Comment: The `NR` values are filtered out with the line `If StrComp(CStr(dVal), "NR", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then` even if they are `nr` or `Nr` so they should be safe. Be careful, I've recently edited the code a few times so make sure you have the latest version.